# Compare X level directory in HDFS using shell script

Tags: shell, hadoop

I have a base directory in HDFS

/user/a123

The HDFS directory a123 has nested sub directories

```
/user/a123/folderA/2017-08-17/xyz
/user/a123/folderA/2017-08-18/abc
/user/a123/folderB/2017-08-17
/user/a123/folderB/2017-08-19
/user/a123/folderC/2017-08-17
/user/a123/folderD/2017-08-20/def
/user/a123/folderD/2017-08-17
/user/a123/folderE/2017-08-17/xyz
```

From the base directory, I need to select only second level directory i.e 'yyyy-mm-dd' directory, and compare if it is older than 2 days.

If it is older than 2 days, print it as archive & the complete folder name else existing.

```
today=`date +'%s'`
hdfs dfs -ls /user/a123/ | grep "^d" | while read line ; do
dir_date=$(echo ${line} | awk '{print $6}')
difference=$(( ( ${today} - $(date -d ${dir_date} +%s) ) / ( 24*60*60 ) ))
filePath=$(echo ${line} | awk '{print $8}')

if [ ${difference} -lt 2 ]; then
echo "Archive : "${filePath}
else echo "Existing : "${filePath}
fi
done
```

Expected output:

```
Archive : /user/a123/folderA/2017-08-17
Archive : /user/a123/folderA/2017-08-18
Archive : /user/a123/folderB/2017-08-17
Existing : /user/a123/folderB/2017-08-19
Archive : /user/a123/folderC/2017-08-17
Existing : /user/a123/folderD/2017-08-20
Archive : /user/a123/folderD/2017-08-17
Archive : /user/a123/folderE/2017-08-17
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with the script or what is your desired goal?

Comment: it is problem with the script.. I need to compare only yyyy-mm-dd directory not all the directories, where as here all the directories are compared.

Comment: Does this work: `hdfs dfs -ls -d /user/a123/*/[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*` ? Also, this `grep "^d"` doesn't work, and below it must read `-gt 2`.

Comment: It dint work  with either changes

Comment: `hdfs dfs -ls /user/a123/*/`

Comment: My idea would be to debug step by step: Check that your `hdfs dfs` returns the right list, then check if the while loop works. Add a `echo $line $dir_date $difference` to see what you get. Update your question with more details.